# Cannot find module 'C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\test.js'

Tags: node.js

Im having an issue getting node.Js to work for me. i keep getting errors when attempting to run simple lines. im not sure what im doing wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjKbM.png)

Comment: PS C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj> node test.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\test.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:768:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)        
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []

is the error if nobody wants to read it

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error as text, not an image. You're running `node test.js` but there's no `test.js` file. You're in the `CodeTProj` folder, so you probably want `node Test/Test1.js`. Also, as a convention, JS files are named in kebab case.

Comment: try `node ./Test/Test.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can see that it is trying to read from /CodeTProj/ instead of /CodeTProj/Test/. All you need to do is navigate to the Test folder using the cd command in command prompt.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out just a bit before you commented